Android studio app text and some details only work on emulator or google pixel devices
Hello I'm a newbie on app development, I'm building a fly tracking app but I have some issues displaying text and some graphics on all devices.
I mean on emulator and google pixel devices all work properly but on other devices some things does not appear, I will put an example.

First Example:
The red circle will show what does appear but on other devices it's not showing up



This is layout code:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainLay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_bg"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme_PopupOverlay">

        <com.dglabs.flytrace.Utils.MediumTextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search By Route"
            android:textColor="@color/toolbartextcolor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.dglabs.flytrace.Utils.MediumTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="From:"
                android:textColor="@color/darktextcolor"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_From"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_bg"
                android:hint="Departure Airport"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/darktextcolor"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_Swap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/up_dwon_arrow_icn" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.dglabs.flytrace.Utils.MediumTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="To:"
                android:textColor="@color/darktextcolor"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_To"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_bg"
                android:hint="Arrival Airport"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/darktextcolor"
                android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_SearchFlight"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_searchflight_selector" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_SearchFlight"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_NoMsg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Flight not found...."
            android:textColor="#262f34"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_above="@+id/banner1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_LiveFlight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/banner1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/banner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/banner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


Another Example: Another view is working on pixel devices and on emulators but not on other device.


code is here: https://pastecode.dev/s/jxbrts8r password: 123456789
Activity code:
issue number one activity code: pastecode.dev/s/bj9ytlco password: 123456789
Issue number 2 activity code: pastecode.dev/s/qapy7qao password: 123456789
So that's all, can someone help me to find a clue? thank you all and sorry maybe for a stupid question... but I can not solve it in any way.
I tried to update all the projects and to search for some solution but nothing, I hope someone can help me find the solution or the issue thanks


Please don't use off-site resources for holding code, instead try to make a Minimum Reproducible Example and add that to your question. 2) Android Studio has layout inspector: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector  Compare the working and non-working versions to see what is different.


Yes Sorry for that but i reach characters limit, so that why i poster links. By the way about the inspector all Is the same but in some device not appear, so the main difference Is that!

I would add in a screenshot of when the section is missing (just the make sure that it isn't a blank space). I would also add in details to your question about how you are adding to your recyclerview and which devices (make/model/OS version) aren't working.

Ok, the part Is missing or not displaying you can see only the background of the app, for example works on pixel device but not on Xiaomi...
